# ImageResizer AzureReader2 404 Error

Tags: imageresizer

We are trying to test the ImageResizer with our Azure Blob Storage. We have included the latest version of everything (including the AzureReader2) but we keep getting the 404 error.

Our config setting is as follows:

```
    <resizer>
        <plugins>
           <add name="AzureReader2" prefix="~/" connectionString="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=ouraccount;AccountKey=ourAccountKey;BlobEndpoint=https://ouraccount.blob.core.windows.net/;TableEndpoint=https://ouraccount.table.core.windows.net/;QueueEndpoint=https://ouraccount.queue.core.windows.net/;FileEndpoint=https://ouraccount.file.core.windows.net/" />
    </plugins>   
</resizer>
```

Is there anything we can do to make this work.
Many thanks

Comment: Try changing the prefix to "~/azure" or any other string

Comment: Thanks for your response. We changed it to azure as above and now we do not get any error but the image does NOT resize. Does this prefix have any significance ? How are we supposed to use it ?

Comment: @NathanaelJones Anything else you can suggest or should we assume that ImageResizer cannot be used in Azure.

Comment: Tens of thousands of people are using ImageResizer with Azure. What URLs are you trying? Can you attach a Gist of the self-diagnostics page per support guidelines?

Comment: @NathanaelJones. We found that the ImageResizer is complaining about licences - Can we not test the azure functionality when our web app is running on localhost and accessing our azure storage account?

Comment: License validation will not affect this. Please show the URLs you are trying.

Comment: @NathanaelJones - Here is the Url: https://bbzstorage.blob.core.windows.net/u0k/1/logo.jpg?width=100&height=60&mode=max

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for sharing the URL you are getting the 404 with in the comments:

https://bbzstorage.blob.core.windows.net/u0k/1/logo.jpg?width=100&height=60&mode=max

This URL is served by `bbzstorage.blob.core.windows.net`. bbzstorage.blob.core.windows.net is not running ImageResizer, so it cannot resize your images.

For ImageResizer to resize an image for you, you must communicate with it somehow. It does not perform a magical man-in-the-middle attack on your network traffic in order to inject its functionality.

If you have an ImageResizer server at localhost, you might need to use a URL like

https://localhost/azure/bbzstorage/u0k/1/logo.jpg?width=100&height=60&mode=max

This diagram tries to explain how data flows. In your case, you don't have a CDN, so just pretend there's a straight line from the rightmost computer to the ImageResizer server.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the diagram. But nothing works! We even uploaded everything including the website with the image resizer libraries into azure and still the images that are in blob storage do not resize while other images that are not in blob storage work as expected..

Comment: Look, given that you won't share the self-diagnostics page, I don't think I can help you further. Diagnosing a problem requires clear communication of steps, methods, and only changing on variable at a time. I don't have anything to work with here.

Comment: Is there anywhere we can email the self-diagnostics page.

Comment: We are desperate to sort this problem out. Could you PLEASE assist us. If there is a paid support where we can resolve this issue faster, please advise. Many thanks.